Whats causing the Schmitt trigger to not produce a clock pulse
I recently built a Boss CE1 clone with all original transistor types except for one sub which is the KSA992 for the 2SA493. I used the UA726 TA7136 to TL071 adapters with TL071s installed. 1458 for the the LFO and the DIY synth MN3002 to TDA1022 adapter board. The rate LED works in both vibrato and chorus mode. The Peak LED works properly. High low switch works properly, but I only get a clean guitar signal in bypass and effect mode. I get very little guitar signal when I use the stereo output in effect mode. Ever diode, transistor, electrolytic cap, IC, and resistor are in the correct spot. I did notice that I get no clock pulses on the collectors of Q5 and Q6 and likewise I get no clock pulses on pins 1 and 4 of the BBD. The CP pins are 2 and 12 on the MN3002. When I probe the Collectors of Q5 and 6 I get a short square wave pulse that quickly goes away. There's also no clock pulse on pin 1 of the 1458 which half is being used as a schmitt trigger. The power supply is a 14 V DC +/- center tapped.



Thanks! Have you tried to simulate (relevant parts of) the schematic?

Anytime, I'm not sure what you mean. Like, build the same circuit on a breadboard and test it by itself?

No, to draw the circuit in a circuit simulator (Falstad, LTspice, ngspice, PSPICE or similar) to understand how the circuit functions and test various conditions to match your experimental findings.

I've never used one before. Can it be downloaded on an Android or is it exclusively for a pc?

Falstad is online, so any modern browser should be fine. Simulation is essential to EEs these days.

@JacobTrybula On mobile OSes, you need an external mouse/trackpad for any serious use of a simulator, whether online or not. Touch interfaces for those are barely usable, and haven't been properly designed for usability. So you may as well do it on a PC. A mobile OS device is not much of a platform for an EE, since the user experience is so poor. An iOS device with a pencil could provide excellent user experience, but few businesses are willing to take that risk. Mobile UX is pretty good for ordering components and reading datasheets, not much else.

@JacobTrybula - Hi, Where did those images come from? In order to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL). If the original source was a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). || Please see the [tour] & [help]. TY

If you disconnect the BBD chip does the clock signal appear when expected?

Unfortunately no. I rechecked every single component placement and everything is in its correct spot and every value is correct to.
